# Pick a file with intent get_content

Tags: android, file, android-intent, filter

I need to pick a file with an extension filter but I have no idea to make it works.

I tried with that :

```
dicomIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
dicomIntent.setType("file/*.dcm"); 
dicomList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(dicomIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

But it only opens dropbox with no filter.

Someone have idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way in Android to pick a file limited by file extension, unless you create your own UI for that yourself. You can limit `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` by MIME type, but not by file extension.

Comment: Is it possible to register custom mime types in my app for that purpose? I haven't figured out how.

Comment: @machtnix: Sorry, but I do not understand. You may wish to ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you can explain your concerns in greater detail.